# How to create an array of Result type in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I create an array of Result type?

```
let results: [Result<String, Error>] = [nameResult, phoneNoResult]
```

The compiler is giving error: **Cannot convert value of type `Result<String, NameValidationError>` to expected element type `Result<String, Error>`**

`nameResult` is of type `enum NameValidationError: String, Error {...}`

`phoneNoResult` is of type `enum PhoneNoValidationError: String, Error {...}`

Is it possible to add these two result types to an array of `Result<String, Error>`?

I want to loop over the array to use the switch-case.

Comment: I believe you can use array inside Result type, something like this `Result<[Model],Error>`. Why you want array of Result type?

Comment: @LeoDabus They might be success or failure depending on the validation.

Comment: @CrackIt I want to use switch-cases for each result.  It becomes repetitive when I have several results.  The codes looks the same for all switch-cases.  I am wondering if I can use for-loop for the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Result` has a `mapError` method you can call.

```
let results = [
    nameResult.mapError { $0 as Error },
    phoneNoResult.mapError { $0 as Error },
]
```

If you like you can create an extension to simplify things:

```
extension Result {
    func hidingErrorType() -> Result<Success, Error> {
        mapError { $0 as Error }
    }
}

let results2 = [
    nameResult.hidingErrorType(),
    phoneNoResult.hidingErrorType(),
]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! It beautifully solves the problem. :)

Comment: the cast to Error is redundant  `mapError{$0}`